# Type conversion for namedtuple fields during initialization

Tags: python, namedtuple, iterable-unpacking

I have a class that has few static fields and is initialized from iterable (like output from `csvreader`). The `__init__` performs type conversion from strings to numbers for some of them:

```
class PerformanceTestResult(object):
    def __init__(self, csv_row):
        # csv_row[0] is just an ordinal number of the test - skip that
        self.name = csv_row[1]          # Name of the performance test
        self.samples = int(csv_row[2])  # Number of measurement samples taken
        self.min = int(csv_row[3])      # Minimum runtime (ms)
        self.max = int(csv_row[4])      # Maximum runtime (ms)
        self.mean = int(csv_row[5])     # Mean (average) runtime (ms)
        self.sd = float(csv_row[6])     # Standard deviation (ms)
```

I’m thinking about converting it to be just a `namedtuple`, as there is not much else to it. But I would like to maintain the type conversion during initialization. Is there a way to do this with `namedtuple`? (I haven’t noticed `__init__` method in the verbose output from `namedtuple` factory method, which gives me pause about how the default initializer works.)

Comment: Do you have an example of how you want your namedtuple to look like?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing in the `csv_row` as-is, like you currently do, you could *unpack* it using the unpack operator `*`. For example:

```
>>> def f(a, b):
...     return a + b
...
>>> csv_row = [1, 2]
>>> f(*csv_row)  # Instead of your current f(csv_row)
```

This would also work with `namedtuple`, since the order of arguments will be kept upon unpacking:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> PerformanceTestResult = namedtuple('PerformanceTestResult', [
...     'name',
...     'samples',
...     'min',
...     'max',
...     'mean',
...     'sd',
... ])
>>> test_row = ['test', '123', 2, 5, 3, None]  # from your csv file
>>> ptr = PerformanceTestResult(*test_row)
>>> ptr
PerformanceTestResult(name='test', samples='123', min=2, max=5, mean=3, sd=None)
```

Not only does this allow you to use `namedtuple`, which seems like a really good idea here, but it also removes the need for your `PerformanceTestResult` to know anything about the CSV file! Abstraction is good, since now you can use this same class regardless of where the data comes from and in what format.

---

If you need the `int()` and `float()` conversions, you're gonna have to write a separate conversion function. You can either build it into the `PerformanceTestResult` by subclassing:

```
_PerformanceTestResult = namedtuple('PerformanceTestResult', [...])

class PerformanceTestResult(_PerformanceTestResult):
    @classmethod
    def from_csv(cls, row):
        return cls(
            row[0],
            int(row[1]),
            int(row[2]),
            int(row[3]),
            int(row[4]),
            int(row[5]),
            float(row[6])
        )
```

Which can be used like so:

```
>>> ptr = PerformanceTestResult.from_csv(your_csv_row)
```

Or you can create a separate conversion function:

```
def parse_csv_row(row):
    return (row[0], int(row[1]), ...)
```

And now use this to convert the row before unpacking:

```
>>> ptr = PerformanceTestResult(*parse_csv_row(your_csv_row))
```